# Can't print value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm using jQuery. I created a variable and I stored the value in it, but I couldn't print it using `.html()`.

**Code**

```
var msg = $("#msg");
var msgvl = msg.val();
var btn = $("#btn");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(btn).click(function(){
    $("#reply").html(msgvl);
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="msg">
<button id="btn">Send!</button>
<p id="reply"></p>
```

Comment: Move your vars inside document ready

Comment: It didn't work like that but i fixed it thanks to your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when document rendered your text-box don't have any value. So your code din't work.

BTW you can do the same through less code like below:-

```js
//compress code to do the same what you did with your code
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(btn).click(function(){
    $("#reply").html($("#msg").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="msg" value="abc"><!-- initially value required to make your code work-->
<button id="btn">Send!</button>
<p id="reply"></p>
```

Note:- if you add value initially also, your code will not work when new value entered into text-box because your code already taken initial value. so if you want it to work for changed value then you have to put all the code above `$(document).ready(function(){..});` inside the `click` function.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlanBns  glad to help you :):). Thanks for marking

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're not dynamically getting the value of the input box. You're setting it as nothing when you load the page. Try this:

```
var msg = $("#msg");
var btn = $("#btn");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(btn).click(function(){
  let msgvl = msg.val();
    $("#reply").html(msgvl);
  });
});
```

The reason it works is because every time you click the button it goes and grabs what's in the input box. The original code only grabbed the initial value(an empty string) and never grabbed a new value when the button was clicked.

```js
var msg = $("#msg");

var btn = $("#btn");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(btn).click(function(){
  let msgvl = msg.val();
    $("#reply").html(msgvl);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="msg"><button id="btn">click me</button>

<div id="reply"></div>
```